# Append To List just overwrites the current List

Tags: automation, robotframework, keyword, robotframework-ide

I have this snippet in my Keyword to store all ids in the test_id_list, but it doesn't seem to work as the latest test_id just overwrites the previous test_id, it does not add to the list.

```
${test_id}    Get Value From JSON    ${response}    $.id
${test_id}    Get From List    ${test_id}    0
${test_id_list}    Create List
Append to List    ${test_id_list}    ${test_id}
```

I have tried:

Removing the 3rd line and declare it like @{test_id_list}=    Create List
AND not removing the 3rd line but just changed it to "@{test_id_list}"

Comment: You haven't posted any code

Answer (score 1):

Overwriting happens because of the code above:

`${test_id_list}    Create List`

So, assume the `test_id_list` is the test or global variable, and the code is run several times. Then, each time, it creates a brand new empty list and assigns it to the `${test_id_list}` variable, dropping the old list.

As there is no bigger piece of your code, I could suggest superficially moving list creation out of this piece of code.

To illustrate the idea and imagining the list of responses, pseudo-code could look like:

```
${test_id_list}    Create List
FOR  ${response}  IN  @{responses}
   ${test_id}        Get Value From JSON    ${response}    $.id
   Append to List    ${test_id_list}    ${test_id}[0]
END
```